# Round off values in 2 columns that have decimal places

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Some of the value in two of my columns have decimal places for some reason, this is a bug in my code I need to sort out but its causing problems at the moment.

How can I round numbers with decimal places?

## Example Data

```
# Table: level_3
|---------------------|
| day_start | day_end |
|-----------|---------|
| -123      | 20      |
| -650      | 234     |
| -133.042..| 104.0416|
| -581      | 123     |
|---------------------|
```

## Expected Output

```
# Table: level_3
|---------------------|
| day_start | day_end |
|-----------|---------|
| -123      | 20      |
| -650      | 234     |
| -133      | 104     |
| -581      | 123     |
|---------------------|
```

**EDIT: If it's any easier, it doesn't need to be rounded, just removed anything after and including the period.**

---

**EDIT 2: I have actually fixed my problem, I just changed the structure to INT and back which removed all the decimals! But thats for the answers, they will help others looking for this!**

Comment: You can use mysql round function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Comment: Can u please mention your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually fixed my problem, I just changed the structure to **INT** and back which removed all the decimals! But thanks for the answers, they will help others looking for this!

Answer (score 1):

Use either the PHP *`floor()`* function, or the mysql *`FLOOR()`* function

PHP

```
<?php
    echo floor(44.62);  // will output "44"
```

MySQL

```
SELECT FLOOR(44.62);
-> 44
```

HOWEVER

```
SELECT FLOOR(-44.62);
-> -45
```

So, you can try something like:

```
SELECT IF(day_start < 0, CEIL(day_start), FLOOR(day_start)) s, IF(day_end < 0, CEIL(day_end), FLOOR(day_end)) e FROM level_3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 simple options:

- Round the values when you query the database, using ROUND, FLOOR, CEIL mysql function

e.g.:`SELECT ROUND(day_start, 0) as day_start, ROUND(day_end, 0) as day_end`

- Round the value using php after you query the database, using `round`, `floor` or `ceil`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using either [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (SQL Server)

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT,Day_Start), CONVERT(INT,Day_End)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (notetitle,1,4), SUBSTRING(notedescription,1,3) FROM notes
```